# Magento 2 : Selected categories are not visible in edit form

Tags: adminform, category-tree, magento-2.1.2, luma-theme, edit

Added category selector in admin form using ui component. The category ids are saved into the db as comma separated values. Now I want to display that categories in my edit form.
[image]

[image]
This is my example_example_edit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="example_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is my example_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">example_form.example_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">example_form.example_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">example Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">example_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Edit\Button\Save</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Edit\Button\Back</item>        
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="example_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Example\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">example_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">example_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">example_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="module/example/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument> 
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="example_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">example [General]</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="openOnShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="example_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">label_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Title</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Company\Module\Model\Config\Source\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
<field name="category_ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset> 

</form>
```

This is my DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Example;

use Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Example\CollectionFactory;;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;  

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_loadedData;

    protected $storeManager;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $exampleCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->collection = $exampleCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }


    /**
    * Get data
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }

    return $this->_loadedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: which theme you using and magento 2(which vertion)

Comment: Magento ver. 2.1.2 {Luma theme}

Comment: Hi @E.B can you help me on this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249360/how-to-add-category-tree-at-attribute-level-in-magento-2-using-ui-components-con

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that case you need to modify **getData** function.

For edit **category_ids** value must be an array.Suppose category_ids value save in db as comma separated that means '7,9,22'. So when you edit this value should be [7,9,22].

```
/**
 * Get data
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    $items = $this->collection->getItems();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $data = $item->getData();
        $data['category_ids'] = explode(',', $data['category_ids']);
        $result['example_details'] = $data;
        $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $result;
    }
    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

Comment: hI @sohel rana please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249360/how-to-add-category-tree-at-attribute-level-in-magento-2-using-ui-components-con

Answer (score 2):

In Your **example_form.xml**  for field **category_ids**

Change this

```
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
```

To

```
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
```

Make sure you are getting values for field category_ids comma separated values magento will do the rest.

Comment: I have changed the code from 'select'  to 'multiselect'. Still it is not working. Also the category ids are saved as comma separated values.

Comment: Possible that `category_ids` does not have a value. Please check if you are getting value for that field. Is the field name same in your db ?

Comment: Yes,the value for the field is getting. The categories are selected in the dropdown as well. But the values are not displaying in the text field.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `getSelected()` method in your component js file

> Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category

If not then you will need to create it and return array with the labels.

```
getSelected: function () {
    var selected = this.value();
    if (selected && selected.indexOf(',') > -1) // split if contains comma only
        selected = selected.split(',');

    return this.cacheOptions.plain.filter(function (opt) {
        return _.isArray(selected) ?
            _.contains(selected, opt.value) :
        selected == opt.value;
    });
},
```

See `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/ui-select.js`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I am not able to add/remove the categories. Please see the screenshot.http://i.prntscr.com/1813b60d309d4a1ab1aac12901b3ae01.png

Comment: There is a js error on editing the categories. Please check this:http://i.prntscr.com/53697deb565d41c2bd482ba15ed5bc43.png

Comment: Change `var selected = this.value().split(",");` and check first if there is some value and then split by comma. I've updated my answer with the check. Can you try again?

Comment: I have tried. But it's not working. http://i.prntscr.com/186eececf7d546f59f7184ff19cb730a.png

Comment: what about now? I updated my code

Comment: I used your code in js file but were not able to unselect selected values. I made a modification like this: getSelected: function () {
           var selected = this.value();
          if (selected && selected.indexOf(',') > -1)
             selected = selected.toString().split(',');

         return this.cacheOptions.plain.filter(function (opt) {
           return _.isArray(selected) ?
            _.contains(selected, opt.value) :
            selected == opt.value;
         });
       }

Comment: Can i add short order Order to this multi select drop down options @MiroslavPetroff

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the ids from Db and put selected when creating options

```
$selectedCat = explode(',', $categoryFromDb)
foreach ($category as $opt) {
    $sel = '';
    if (in_array($opt, $selectedCat)) {
    $sel = ' selected="selected" ';
    }
    echo '<option ' . $sel . ' value="' . $opt . '">' . $opt . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: The category field is created using ui component.

Comment: @E.B Please put your code to get proper answer according to your code.

Comment: Please see the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert the string to array using explode function, like below:

```
/* Get data
 * @return array
 */

public function getData()
{
    if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    $items = $this->collection->getItems();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $data = $item->getData();
        $data['category_ids'] = explode(',', $data['category_ids']);
        $final_data['details'] = $data;
        $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $final_data['details'];
    }
    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest this need some modification.
I have also need the same but end of i found below solutions, So it will help to other which are looking for the same.

your xml file(ie.) :

> view->adminhtml->ui_component->module_module_form.xml

```
<dataSource name="module_module_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\Name\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">crossell_crossell_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="crossell/crossell/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

---

```
<field name="category">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Co-related Category</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Now, Your DataProvider will be in:

> Model->Name->DataProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Name;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\PoolInterface;
use Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Name\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var PoolInterface
     */
    protected $pool;
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param PoolInterface $pool
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        PoolInterface $pool,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->pool         = $pool;
        $this->meta         = $this->prepareMeta($this->meta);
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares Meta
     *
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function prepareMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = parent::getMeta();

        foreach ($this->pool->getModifiersInstances() as $modifier) {
            $meta = $modifier->modifyMeta($meta);
        }
        return $meta;
    }

    public function addFilter(Filter $filter){
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collectionFactory->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $data = $item->getData();
            $data['category'] = explode(',', $data['category']);
            $this->loadedData[$item->getId()] = $data;
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('name');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $block = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $block->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$block->getId()] = $block->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('crossell');
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

}
```

Wokring fine for me & It looks like :

[image]